# Detect users previous domain

Tags: html, web

I have a small loading animation that I want to run on my Home page when a user is coming from outside my domain, but when coming from another page inside my domain I don't want it to show.

I have tried using `document.domain` and `document.referrer.split...` to get the previous domain, and run an if-command but can't seem to make it work.

Edit:

I tried using the `if`-command and `document.referrer.split...`-command, again as an answerer stated but the animation still always shows and now it never stops as well...

```
<head>
<body>
<div class="loader"></div>

<style>.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('http://bosonprotein.com/onewebmedia/Magiska%20Bollar.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(0,0,0);
    background-size: 10%;
}

</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.referrer.split('/')[2]!=location.hostname){
   $(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
            $('.loader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        },1000);
   })
}
else{
}

</script>
</body>
</head>
```

Comment: Should this animation always load, for example when a user visit your home page the second time?

Comment: Yes, is very short so I only want it to hide when the user is going back to the homepage from within the site.

Comment: Then use a session cookie as _norcal johnny_ suggest, as the referrer domain might not always be there

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the referrer url using this technique:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = document.referrer;

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;
```

`parser.host` will return the domain from the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detect the domain, you could use a cookie and jQuery, maybe something like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome">
  <div>
    <h1>Hello..!<br> Welcome to ABC
    <br>
    </h1>
    <h2>We wish you a Great Day..!</h2>
    <br>

    <h2><a id="close-welcome" href="#">Thank you.. and please take me to the     website</a> </h2>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('noShowWelcome')) $('.welcome').hide();
    else {
        $("#close-welcome").click(function() {
            $(".welcome").fadeOut(1000);
            $.cookie('noShowWelcome', true);    
        });
    }
});
```

This will load it per session only.

Answer (score 0):

`document.refferer.split()` is the right solution for solve your problem.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer), `document.refferer` return the URI of the previous page.

Compare the splitted URI with the `location.host` like the following code snippet:

```
if(document.referrer.split('/')[2]!=location.hostname){
   //I came from another domain
}else{
   //I came from this domain
}
```

I used this solution in different projects and it works.

Comment: I tried this by putting the animation script instead of "//I came from another...", now the animation still always shows up and never stops...